# Binding Rectangle.widthProperty() to its parent width does not work

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to place an `HBox` with a red rectangle in the middle of a `BorderPane`, and I would like that rectangle to grow or shrink with its container (the HBox).
This is my code:

```
public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        HBox hBox = new HBox();

        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(hBox.getWidth(),50);
        rect.setFill(Color.RED);
        rect.widthProperty().bind(hBox.widthProperty().subtract(20));

        hBox.getChildren().add(rect);

        borderPane.setCenter(hBox);     

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 900, 600, Color.WHITE);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. When I slowly resize my Frame, it works, nevertheless, when I quickly resize my Frame, the rectangle is not in the middle (not the same size too) and we can see the same things when we minimize and maximize the Frame.

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your English is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is happening:

When `rect` is asked for the preferred/minimum/maximum width during layout, it replies with its current width, which is before resize, because by that time `hBox` has not been resized yet. As a result, `hBox`'s minimum width is reported to be its current width minus 20. Therefore, when you shrink the window, the `hBox` will still be resized to its previous width minus 20.

There are a number of ways how to go around this, but a more accurate answer depends on what you are trying to do, and may involve using `Region` instead of a `Rectangle`, or overriding `layoutChildren` method of the rectangle's parent.

Here is a way that is close to what you have now. It defines a *resizable rectangle* and overrides its minimum width to be 0.0, so it allows the HBox to be downsized.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RectangleAutosize extends Application {

    static class ResizableRectangle extends Rectangle {
        ResizableRectangle(double w, double h) {
            super(w, h);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isResizable() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public double minWidth(double height) {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        HBox hBox = new HBox();

        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Rectangle rect = new ResizableRectangle(hBox.getWidth(),50);
        rect.setFill(Color.RED);
        rect.widthProperty().bind(hBox.widthProperty().subtract(20));

        hBox.getChildren().add(rect);

        borderPane.setCenter(hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 900, 600, Color.WHITE);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have a last question about your post : if I comment (not override) the method "isResizable()" in the class "ResizableRectangle", it works very well too. So, why have you add an overriding of this method ? Thanks for your answer and all your clear explanations.

Comment: @Florian I see, you can leave it out in this case. In general, if a node is not resizable, its parent (here `HBox`) will not try to resize it in order to satisfy some layout constraints. You don't need it here, because you are resizing your rectangle on your own. If you, for example, wanted the `HBox` to resize the rectangle to fill it's own height, the rectangle would have to be resizable.